# Bison and Flex using codeblocks and Dev-C++ both compile file but exe file close after opening?

Tags: c, bison, lex

So I'm trying to build boolean calculator with the output True or false for some reason my file exe file is created and is not working I had some issues along the way with installing flex,bison,gcc and I managed to deal with those currently I can't figure out what the problem is and I really need help working on Windows and not sure if this is the problem.

This is my l file:

```
%{
#include "boolcalc.tab.h"
%}

%%

[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*  { yylval.identifier = strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER; }
"and"                 { return AND; }
"or"                  { return OR; }
"not"                 { return NOT; }

[ \t]                 ; /* skip whitespace */
\n                    { return '\n'; }

.                     { printf("Invalid character: %s\n", yytext); }
```

And this is the y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX_EXPR_LENGTH 100

int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *);

bool stack[MAX_EXPR_LENGTH];
int top = -1;

%union {
    char* identifier;
}

%token IDENTIFIER AND OR NOT

%left OR
%left AND
%right NOT

%type <identifier> expression

%}

%%

input:
    | line '\n'   { printf("%s\n", $1); }
    ;

line: expression
    | error '\n'       { printf("Invalid expression\n"); }
    ;

expression:
        IDENTIFIER     { yystack[top + 1].identifier = $1; top++; }
    |   expression AND expression { stack[top-1] &= stack[top]; top--; }
    |   expression OR expression { stack[top-1] |= stack[top]; top--; }
    |   NOT expression { stack[top] = !stack[top]; }
    ;

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    yyparse();
    getchar(); // Pause the program until a key is pressed
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use console to work but it also doesn't work

Comment: There is a bunch of errors printed both by Flex and Bison when I try to compile your program. Fix them. The main problem, that may cause a segmentation fault, is that you've used `yystack` in one line. This is some internal Bison variable that is not even in the manual so it's not intended to be used outside of Bison-generated functions. You've probably meant `stack`.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your `IDENTIFIER` token.  Is this supposed to support boolean constants?  If so, then why not instead just provide specific tokens for those, say `TRUE` and `FALSE`, or else a generic `CONSTANT` with an appropriate (boolean) semantic value?  The only other purpose I can imagine is for names for variables or user-defined functions, but I see none of the other framework that would be required for your calculator to support variables or functions.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you need an operand stack in the first place.  It would be more natural to use the semantic values of your non-terminals to carry intermediate results.

Comment: My knowledge in C is very basic today is the first day in fact when I use it, not exactly sure  yet how things are working never even used codeblocks before which makes me a total noob :D thank you for suggestions.

Comment: The issues with this program are mostly about Bison, not about C.  The specific failure you observe is probably related to @PiotrSiupa's comment, but the best way to fix it is probably to get rid of your `stack` altogether, and, as I wrote earlier, rely exclusively on the semantic values of your Bison tokens and productions to carry operand and result values.  I anticipate that that will also help clarify some higher-level issues with your calculator grammar.